# g++ How to get warning on ignoring function return value

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, return-value, compiler-warnings

lint produces some warning like:

```
foo.c XXX Warning 534: Ignoring return value of function bar()
```

From the lint [manual](http://legacy.cleanscape.net/products/cpp/checks.html)

> 534   Ignoring return value of function
>
> 'Symbol' (compare with Location)   A
>   function that returns a value is
>   called just for side effects as, for
>   example, in a statement by itself or
>   the left-hand side of a comma
>   operator.  Try: (void) function(); to
>   call a function and ignore its return
>   value.  See also the fvr, fvo and fdr
>   flags in §5.5 "Flag Options".

I want to get this warning, if there exists any, during compilation. Is there any option in gcc/g++ to achieve this? I had turned on `-Wall` but that apparently did not detect this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to [WhirlWind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301023/whirlwind) and [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) for the answer and comment. Here is my attempt to put the pieces together into a complete (?) answer.

`-Wunused-result` *is* the relevant gcc option. And *it is turned on by default*. Quoting from [gcc warning options page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> `-Wno-unused-result`
>
> Do not warn if a caller of a function marked with attribute `warn_unused_result` (see 
>   [Variable Attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes)) does not use its return value. The default is `-Wunused-result`

So, the solution is to apply the `warn_unused_result` attribute on the function.

Here is a full example. The contents of the file unused_result.c

```
int foo() { return 3; }

int bar() __attribute__((warn_unused_result));
int bar() { return 5; }

int main()
{
    foo();
    bar();    /* line 9 */
    return 0;
}
```

and corresponding compilation result:

```
$gcc unused_result.c 
unused_result.c: In function ‘main’:
unused_result.c:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘bar’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
```

Note again that **it is not necessary to have -Wunused-result** since it is default. One may be tempted to explicitly mention it to communicate the intent. Though that is a noble intent, but after analyzing the situation, my choice, however, would be against that. Because, having `-Wunused-result` in the compile options may generate a false sense of security/satisfaction which is not true unless the **all** the functions in the code base are qualified with `warn_unused_result`.

Comment: if `-Wunused-result` is the default, how come the compiler (gcc 9.2.1) is not warning me about ignoring `fgets` return value? one of the most important purposes of `fgets` is to precisely return a byte from the stream, so ignoring it could be a big deal.

Comment: @m4l490n Maybe `fgets` is not _"marked with attribute `warn_unused_result`"_ (and maybe it should be)?

Answer (score 35):

Since C++17 you can use the [`[[nodiscard]]` attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

Example:

```
[[nodiscard]] int bar() {
  return 42;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that this only means that the compiler is [encouraged to issue a warning](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) (no guarantee)

Comment: And in C++20 you can add message string: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard

Answer (score 9):

`-Wunused-result` should do this for you.  This isn't one of the warnings -Wall turns on:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

The function has to have the warn_unused_result attribute applied to it (Thanks paxdiablo).

Answer (score 8):

The answers about using `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` are correct.  GCC isn't so good at this functionality, though!  Be aware: it will not warn for non-POD types.  That means, for example, if you return a class with a destructor (or a class with instance variables with destructors) you'll never see a warning about ignoring the result.

Relevant bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66177

Example where it fails:

```
struct Error {
~Error();
};

__attribute__((warn_unused_result)) Error test();

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

So, don't rely on this for return types which aren't pretty simple.

Comment: some additional relevant bugzillas: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38172  and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46643

Answer (score -4):

I solved the problem like this:

```
#define ignore_result(x) if (x) {}
```

then instead of `(void)foo()` use `ignore_result(foo())`

Then the code compiles with `-Wall` just fine.

Comment: The OP question was to reliably get the warning not to prevent getting it.