# Forcing function to be called as assignment operand only

Tags: c++

Is it possible to declare a function in such a way that

```
auto i = foo.GetLock();
```

works, but

```
foo.GetLock();
```

causes a compile error?

My interface has a method that returns RIIA-style lock object and I want to make sure nobody decides just calling GetLock() locks the lock.

It used to be something like this

```
class CSomethingOrElse : private CLockable
{
    ...
} foo;

CLocker<CSomethingOrElse> lock(foo);
```

but it's too verbose for my taste and I would really like to make use of `auto`.

Comment: If getLock returns a class, which unlocks on destruction : it will not prevent non-assignment call as you wish, but it will prevent locked lock

Comment: clang and gcc have a warning for that (using the returned value of function). (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870529/g-how-to-get-warning-on-ignoring-function-return-value)

Comment: @Jarod42 : but you will generally have tons of warnings in that case, no? A lot of functions use optional return values (such as stream operators, etc...)

Comment: @galinette: the warning works with attribute, so only the specified functions provoke the warning.

Answer (score 1):

`foo.GetLock();` is an *expression statement*, so any valid expression can be used in that way. You cannot prohibit that at compile time: the best you can get is a warning.

Assuming that your object releases the lock on destruction, the call that does not store the result in a variable shouldn't be a big problem, because the lock would be acquired and released right away.

Creating a *guard object*, similar to what you describe in your solution, is the proper way to go. In fact, the Standard Library of C++ does it in a similar way with [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).