# Is it considered bad practise to not store the return value from a member function c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have a member function that returns an integer, would it be considered bad practise on the odd occasion to call the member function and not store the return value.

**Edit.**

An example of this would be a function that appends an item to a vector and returns the index of the appended item.

A simplified example.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> myVector; 

int AppendVector(int value)
{
    myVector.push_back(value);
}

int main()
{
    AppendVector(3);
    AppendVector(4);

    int indexOfValue = AppendVector(2);
    // do action on appended value 
}
```

Comment: Not at all. E.g. `T::operator=` usually returns `T&`, but it's rare for this return value to actually be used.

Comment: There are plenty of instances where you'd want to ignore the return, even if the return is indicating the success or failure of the function

Comment: Why does it return an integer?

Comment: Do you store the return value of printf?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, and it is quite common to do so. There are plenty of functions which are used regularly while ignoring the return value.

Some examples you've likely used or seen:

- `std::printf` which returns the number of characters written.
- `operator<<` which returns the stream, and is ultimately discarded
- `std::vector::erase` which returns an iterator just after the last element removed
- `std::map::insert` which returns an iterator and a status

For cases where the return value is especially important, C++17 added the `[[nodiscard]]` [attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

Proior to C++17 you'd have to use something compiler specific such as gcc's `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889601/1013719) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to depend entirely on what the return-value means, and what the caller is trying to accomplish by making the method-call.

The person writing the calling code should definitely be thinking about what (if anything) he wants to do with the return value, though; a common newbie mistake is to ignore a return value rather than examining it, and thus fail to act appropriately e.g. if the return value indicated that the method's operation has failed.

One semi-common idiom you might see is this:

```
(void) someObject.Method();
```

The (void) prefix doesn't do anything (the compiler will ignore it), but it does serve as an indicator to the human reader that the person who wrote that line is *deliberately* ignoring the return value, rather than failing to understand that a value was returned.  It doesn't change the way the program behaves, but it does keep future readers of the source code from wondering if they are looking at a mistake or if the ignoring was intentional.

Comment: *"(the compiler will ignore it"*. It will use it to not warn in case of `[[nodiscard]]` attribute. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/389cee4da56657ee)